# TextMate and Django Integration - Supporting {% %} markup

Tags: python, django, textmate

I have installed a TextMate bundle that I believe enables the ability for automatic closing of the "{{" markup (so that it will automatically close the markup with "}}"), but this does not seem to be possible with the other markup that uses "{%" and "%}".

So, I was wondering if anyone out there knows how to get TextMate to add the automatic closing tags for the {% %} just like is already done with {{ }}.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It's possible - the Rails bundle does this for ERB (<% automatically gets closing %> tags).

So that's a place you could go look.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible, but the Django bundle for TextMate does allow you to insert the opening and closing tags in one go, placing the cursor in the middle, with ctrl-% (ctrl-shift-5).

Click the Bundles -> Python Django Templates menu to see all the shortcuts that are available.